# Calculating Upper Fence using Math.js

Tags: javascript, statistics, mathjs

I have a list of numbers in an array and I would like to calculate the Upper Fence.

I know I'll have to calculate the median, that can be done using the math.js library.

```
var median = math.median(numList);
```

And then the third quartile is the upper half of the median. I would think I would have to sort first, I believe this can be done by,

```
numList.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});
```

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here on calculating the 3rd quartile and interquartile range to get the Upper Fence.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could just keep using median and let [Math.js](http://mathjs.org/) do the sorting for you.

```
function quartileBounds(_sample){
    // find the median as you did
    var _median = math.median(_sample)

    // split the data by the median
    var _firstHalf = _sample.filter(function(f){ return f < _median })
    var _secondHalf = _sample.filter(function(f){ return f >= _median })

    // find the medians for each split
    var _25percent = math.median(_firstHalf);
    var _75percent = math.median(_secondHalf);

    var _50percent = _median;
    var _100percent = math.max(_secondHalf);

    // this will be the upper bounds for each quartile
    return [_25percent, _50percent, _75percent, _100percent];
}

quartileBounds([7,18,33,32,10,30,77,40,135,30,121,36,26,28,60,80,17,288,114]);
// returns [26,33,78.5,288]
```